# Как узнать значение нового списка после перетаскивания .sortable()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, sortable

У меня есть код.

```
<ul data-id-status="1" class="tasot_suppilo_block">
  <li data-id-lead="24">
    <div class="drag-item-suppilo-status">...</div>
    24
  </li>
  <li data-id-lead="25">
    <div class="drag-item-suppilo-status">...</div>
    25
  </li>
</ul>

<ul data-id-status="2" class="tasot_suppilo_block">
  <li data-id-lead="26">
    <div class="drag-item-suppilo-status">...</div>
    26
  </li>
  <li data-id-lead="27">
    <div class="drag-item-suppilo-status">...</div>
    27
  </li>
</ul>
```

js

```
 $( "<?=$options?>" ).sortable({
                                            connectWith: ".tasot_suppilo_block",
                                            cancel: ".title_suppilo",
                                            items: 'li', // Указывает какие элементы в группе могут быть отсортированы. 
                                            handle: '.drag-item-suppilo-status', //Указывает элемент, при щелчке на который начнется перетаскивание. 
                                            helper:'original', // Устанавливает вид элемента помощника  original или clone
                                            opacity:1, // прозрачность перетаскиваемого элемента
                                            cursor: 'n-resize', // вид курсора при нажатии
                                            revert: 'true', // эффект вставляния перетаскиваемого элемента
                                            placeholder:"ui-state-highlight",
                                            stop: sortList,
                                            beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
                                                console.log(''+ui.item.data('id-lead')+'); // свойство item объекта ui представляет перемещаемый элемент
                                            }

                                        }).disableSelection();
```

Мне нужно перетаскивая из одного списка в другой узнавать значение data-id-lead (узнаю) перетаскиваемого элемента и значение data-id-status списка куда перетащили элемент.

**Как узнать значение data-id-status в который перетащили элемент?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log(ui.item.parent().data('id-status')); // свойство item объекта ui представляет перемещаемый элемент
    }
```

Comment: Искал просто долго нашел чуть-чуть раньше вас, но все равно благодарю. Уже сделал.